# Quarkus / Smallrye Reactive Messaging - message redelivery

Tags: quarkus, activemq-artemis, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I'm currently investigating the Smallrye Reactive Messaging integration in Quarkus.Sending and receiving messages is really simple and elegant at first glance.

But one thing which I didn't find out is: **How to handle a re-delivery of messages?**

**Example:** We receive a message and try to process it. Some exception (maybe a DB not available or an optimistic lock exception or something) happens.
In such a case I would throw an exception so that the message is not acknowledged. But currently I see no way how the message is redelivered.

I set-up a small dummy project to test this:

- Quarkus
- ActiveMQ Artemis
- send a message (via Artemis console) into a queue 
  -- queue configured with max redelivery = 3
- receive the message with Quarkus / Smallrye Reactive Messaging @Incoming annotation
- throw exception in the @Incoming method 
  --> Message is removed from the Artemis queue  
  --> @Incoming method is only called once

If I shutdown the Quarkus App, the message can be seen again in the Artemis queue with redelivered flag set to true.

But I find no way how I can manage/configure a redelivery in the Smallrye Reactive Messaging so that this layer handles the redelivery of a message for n times and puts the message into a DLQ after the max retries.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to make your question more readable.

Comment: Please raise an issue https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-reactive-messaging/issues for the community of that project to provide assistance

Comment: You can check smallrye-reactive messaging documentation regarding manual acknowledgement and default strategies :https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/#_acknowledgement